# how to find the index positions of particular BBCode tag (Regex)

Tags: c#, regex, bbcode

I have a string, let's say:

```
[s]AB[/s]23[sb]45[/sb]AB45ABABAB
```

I want to find all indexes that are surrounded by a tag that contains the letter s, so that includes [s] and [sb].

A function call to **findIndices("[s]01[/s]23[sb]45[/sb]AB45ABABAB", "s")** would return the List [0, 1, 4, 5]. Note that the indices ignores all BBCode. In other words, it thinks the index of the first 'A' character is 0, not 3.

How does one implement findIndices in C#. I tried using System.Text.RegularExpressions but I am having trouble, the difficulty is in finding the index relative to the string that has the BBCode stripped out.

Comment: You cannot do it only with a regex. See my answer.

Comment: @Laurianti depending on how it should handle poorly-nested tags, a regex might actually be ideal for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only an example, you can try this way, test here: http://rextester.com/FMTZ35054

```
    public class Entity
    {
        public string Text {get; set;}
        public int Index {get; set;}

        public int CountDirty {get; set;}

        public int CountClean {get; set;}
        public int CountGross {get; set;}

        public int IndexStart {get; set;}
        public int IndexEnd {get; set;}

        public int IndexStartClean {get; set;}
        public int IndexEndClean {get; set;}

        public int IndexStartGross {get; set;}
        public int IndexEndGross {get; set;}

        public int CountBefore {get;set;}
        public int CountAfter {get;set;}
    }

    public static List<Entity> findIndices(string text)
    {
        string regex = @"(\[[a-zA-Z]*\])(.*?)(\[/[[a-zA-Z]*\])";
        Regex r = new Regex(regex);

        MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(text);

        List<Entity> list = new List<Entity>();

        int accumulation = 0;
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Entity t = new Entity();

            string stringa2 = match.ToString();

            t.CountBefore = match.Groups[1].ToString().Count();
            t.CountAfter = match.Groups[3].ToString().Count();

            t.CountClean = match.Groups[2].ToString().Count();
            t.CountGross = match.ToString().Count();
            t.CountDirty = t.CountClean - t.CountGross;
            t.Text = stringa2;
            t.IndexStart = match.Index;
            t.IndexEnd = match.Index + t.CountGross - 1;

            t.IndexStartGross = t.IndexStart + t.CountBefore;
            t.IndexEndGross = t.IndexStartGross + t.CountClean - 1;

            t.IndexStartClean = t.IndexStartGross - t.CountBefore - accumulation;
            t.IndexEndClean = t.IndexStartClean + t.CountClean - 1;

            list.Add(t);

            accumulation += t.CountBefore + t.CountAfter;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

And this is an implementation:

```
        List<Entity> list = findIndices("[s]AB[/s]23[sb]45[/sb]AB45ABABAB[a]test[/a]");

        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            var l = list[i];

            Console.WriteLine("Text = " + l.Text);

            Console.WriteLine("IndexStartClean = " + l.IndexStartClean);
            Console.WriteLine("IndexEndClean = " + l.IndexEndClean);

            Console.WriteLine("---");
        }
```

Comment: You legend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A regex pattern like this `(?<=[^/]s.?\]).+?(?=\[)` will match e.g. `AB` and `45`

We check to see (lookbehind) if there is an `s` and a `]` behind us, but no `/`, and then match characters until we hit a `[`. There may be edge cases I've missed, so exert some caution & test it out.

(If you need the indexes specifically, you can get those from the regex match objects)